# Why isn't my histogram showing on Jupyter notebook?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, netcdf, python-iris

So I'm relatively new to coding and have recently taken the monstrous task of building a few climate models for my MSc thesis. Using this code I have adapted it and it now shows no error messages except now it doesn't show any figure as an output. Any solutions?

I input

`%matplotlib notebook` at the top of the code, and also put `plt.show();` at the bottom of the script (as per some recommendations through some similar queries)... but still doesn't work. Prior to this it was showing <Figure Ssize 432x288 with 0 Axes> which i presumed may be the problem but i can't figure out why there are 0 axes?

Any recommendations/solutions?

Thanks!

As requested - my code:

```
import iris.quickplot as qplt
import iris.analysis.cartography
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def main():
    Current45 = '....X.nc'

    Current45 = iris.load_cube(Current45)

    lats = iris.coords.DimCoord(Current45.coords()[1].points[:,0], \
                                standard_name='latitude', units='degrees')
    lons = Current45.coords()[2].points[0]
    for i in range(len(lons)):
        if lons[i]>100.:
            lons[i] = lons[i]-360.
    lons = iris.coords.DimCoord(lons, \
                                standard_name='longitude', units='degrees')
    Current45.remove_coord('latitude')
    Current45.remove_coord('longitude')
    Current45.add_dim_coord(lats, 1)
    Current45.add_dim_coord(lons, 2)

    Current45.convert_units('Celsius') 

    Colombia = iris.Constraint(longitude=lambda v: -74.73 <= v <= -76.20, \
                               latitude=lambda v: 5.30 <= v <= 4.43) 

    Current45 = Current45.extract(Colombia) 

    iriscc.add_day_of_year(Current45, 'time') 

    Current45.coord('latitude').guess_bounds()
    Current45.coord('longitude').guess_bounds()

    Current45_grid_areas = iris.analysis.cartography.area_weights(Current45)

    Current45 = Current45.collapsed(['latitude', 'longitude'],
                                               iris.analysis.MEAN,
                                               
    weights=Current45_grid_areas)    

    Histogram = Current45.data

    #frq, bins, patches = plt.hist(Histogram, bins=np.arange(20,37,2))
    frq, bins, patches = plt.hist(Histogram, bins=np.arange(16,45,2), color='blue')
    print (frq)


    thresh = 32
    plt.axvline(x=thresh, color='green', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)      

    plt.xlabel("Daily Max Temperature / Celsius")
    plt.ylabel("Number of days")

fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show();
```

[My code with blank figure at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF3GX.png)

Comment: if you don't have axes, `pyplot` also can't show anything as far as I know. Could you post your code ([minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) to help us help you and figure out the problem?

Comment: The image of the code seems to suggest that the function `main` is never called. Just add `main()` somewhere without indentation

Comment: Thanks @Dorian, i've now included the code (unaware of what "minimal" really means considering I think all of that is necessary to understand why the figure isn't showing (TL:DR; I am a novice at code)

Comment: I think this confusion comes from the fact, that many programming languages look for a `main` function and execute that. But python is not like that; you have to actively call every function you write in order to execute it

Comment: could you potentially close the question if it is solved? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, you are never calling the `main` function, so the figure you are showing is empty.

You should call `main()` at some point in your code before the `plt.gcf()` or `plt.show`.

**Edit**

In more detail:

You are writing your `main()` function in this snippet of code, and then, without indent, you are calling `pyplot` to get the current `figure`, where `pyplot` just gives you en empty `figure` back (the `gcf()`-call is not necessary anyways in your code) and `plt.show()` shows no an empty figure.

You can or cannot move the `plt.show()` into you `main()` function, but at one point you must definitely call that function otherwise none of it is executed.

**Edit 2:**

```
# function definition
def main():
    ...

# function call
main()

# show figure
plt.show()
```

Comment: Okay so thanks for that, at what point should I be inputting `main()` ? Bit confused by your explanation

Comment: at the end of your code. You are **defining** your function, but never **calling** it. Which basically means, after you have written all your code, it will **not** be executed.

Comment: think about what code you wrote: there is a `print()` statement somewhere, but nothing prints to the console. this should give you the hint that the code isn't executed.

Comment: Okay dude, i've put it at the end of the script now and had some re-jigs but i cannot get this script to work! now its saying:

"OSError: One of more of the files specified did not exist:"

and highlights the .nc file above.. I cannot for the life of me understand why it is not recognising the .nc file?

Comment: that's a separate question though, so consider reopening another one for that problem.

Comment: most probably, the `.nc` file is not in the directory/path that you are running the script from. You have to give python the full absolute path, or the correct relative path (which might be difficult since the jupyter notebook might not be run from the same directory as it is in) to find the file. but please open another question with the full file-path and directory structure since this is unrelated.